Error while updating Account field while updating created Speaker record
I have created one Speaker record and i want to update/add "Account" field value, but receiving this error while saving it. So, can someone please let me know how to resolve this issue?
Error: An error occurred while trying to update the record. Please try again.
OCE.SpeakerTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0019L0000036FcTQAU; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY, insufficient access rights on object id: [] (OCE)
Also, please find the reference screenshot attached:

Thanks,
Rudraswamy

I guess you know there's a trigger running that's causing the problem.
The trigger probably needs some exception handling, so it doesn't just break things in Salesforce. That's sort of programming 101 in Salesforce.
Next thing is why it's breaking:

probably security, someone has access to 1 object or field and not the other
the poorly written trigger is then trigger something else, which breaks the initial trigger
DMLException can be a lot of things, including DML limit, or security
or it can be the user doesn't have a permission set (might be OSE since it looks like you might have that)

My suggestion - find the trigger - get it written better. then review security.

This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, you will be able to post comments.
